# Extracting single boundary from multipolygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, query, boundaries

[image: example]

I am trying to find a single external boundary either polygon or line from the multipolygon using `st_boundary` in PostGIS query. The function doesn't work. What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you please show us some graphics/code/error reports that you have

Comment: `select st_boundary(geom) from (select polygon(geo_gem_05)::geometry As geom) As f;` This is the query where geo_gem_05 is a multipolygon.

Comment: Edit the question, don't put clarification in comments. And, please state how it is not working.

Comment: geo_gem_05 is the polygon which I am defining here

Comment: @Karthik literally put your code comment in the question

Comment: and provide some sample data because we do not know what goe_gem_05 contains

Comment: that is the shape file I have.

Comment: In this case, your request might look like this: select st_boundary(geom) as geom from geo_gem_05

Comment: I got the output but I need the single external boundary so that I could do the analysis from that single boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand your question a little and therefore I will offer you two possible answers, use the one that answers your question

Option 1 - to find all boundaries, run the query:

`SELECT ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) as geom FROM geo_gem_05;`

Option 2 - to find only a common external boundary, run the query:

`SELECT ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(ST_Union(geom))).geom) as geom FROM geo_gem_05;`

for experiment you can replace "ST_ExteriorRing" for "ST_Boundary"

Good luck ...

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "The function doesn't work"? It does work for me.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Boundary(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON ((( 340 520, 400 460, 200 420, 340 520 )), (( 420 420, 520 300, 340 320, 420 420 )))')));


Result:
MULTILINESTRING((340 520,400 460,200 420,340 520),(420 420,520 300,340 320,420 420))
```

The result is a multilinestring with two closed linestrings, one for each member in the multipolygon. That is the correct result by the definition of a boundary https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Boundary.html. Please explain if you are after something else.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer by applying Cyril's query.

```
SELECT ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(ST_Union(geom))).geom) as geom FROM geo_gem_05;
or
SELECT ST_Boundary((ST_Dump(ST_Union(geom))).geom) as geom FROM geo_gem_05;
```

The resultant output is given below
[image]